# What is a "default host triple" in Rust?

Tags: rust, rustup

While doing a custom installation of Rust on Windows 10, I am asked "Default host triple?"

I have no clue what this is, and [the Rustup repository page](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs), which came up in a web search, does not really explain it.

Comment: It's no longer a target "triple" but  a quintic value. Check [target-lexicon](https://docs.rs/target-lexicon/latest/target_lexicon/struct.Triple.html)'s `struct Triple` for the fields and the definition: _Historically such things had three fields, though they’ve added additional fields over time._

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Host triples identify the architecture and OS of the system that will ultimately run your executable.  Mine is `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` for example.  The general form is `cpu-vendor-os`.  Windows might be something like `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc`.  You can read more at these links:

- [Automake cross compilation](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html)
- [Clang cross compilation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html)

Comment: Not surprised that it has an Automake history.  I have always hated Autotools.

Comment: @Sabuncu: Actually, it has no automake history. This is a fundamental building block of compilers, and automake just had to deal with it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Oh, OK then.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Are you sure about that?  I was under the impression that the specific cpu-vendor-os format was a GNU invention.

Comment: @TavianBarnes: I am not sure how being a GNU invention would not make it a compiler specificity? Triplets appear out of the need of cross-compiling, I would expect, as a compiler which only ever generates code for the platform it runs on need not be aware of any target triplet.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'm questioning whether they are a "fundamental building block of compilers" since compilers are much older than the GNU project.  There are also other compilers (MSVC for example) that don't use that format.

Comment: @TavianBarnes: Ah! You are trying to read way too much in my statement, I fear. (1) I was more talking about cross-compiling capabilities, and a way to indicate the target, than about platform triplets specifically to be honest. (2) Cross-compiling is only something native AOT compilers care about; JIT compilers don't care, compilers to IR don't care, ... So, yes, the sentence is not as precise as it could be; it's a careless comment, not a carefully thought-out answer.

Comment: For my `Ubuntu` it shows: `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.
Now [I understand](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CrossCompilation.html#general-cross-compilation-options-in-clang) what is it!
`arch = x86_64`, `vendor = unknown`, `sys = linux`, `abi = gnu`

Comment: intresting, but windows ist not a vendor :P

Comment: @Sebi2020 Right, "windows" is the OS.  The vendor is "pc" or possibly "unknown"

Comment: If I'm developing on windows but I'm ONLY targeting esp32 (esp32c3), do I still need the "linker and Windows API libraries" that rustup wants to see?  What is the right default host triple?  rustup doesn't ultimately like the target "riscv32im-unknown-none-elf" as a host-triple.